# Where is the Ace Editor source code being maintained?

Tags: ace-editor

Where is the Ace Editor source code being maintained. There are numerous sites on the internet returning results. What is the official location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ace editor's source code is maintained in two different repositories:

1. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace 
   If you just want to use ace directly on your app/website.
2. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/ 
   Contains pre-built files

Answer (score 0):

The source code appears to be in the AJAXORG repository [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/editor.js).